# Why am I only getting 92V at receptacles?

Tags: electrical

There are about 5 or 6 receptacles in 2 rooms that all stopped working at once. We were getting a reading of about 92V and it's a 120V circuit. We changed out the receptacles but still the same results. Any ideas for me to fix this? Extension cords through the house are no fun.

Comment: You've checked the breaker box?

Comment: Is this 92V reading happening with loads plugged in and turned on, or with nothing plugged in? If you feel safe in a main-off breaker panel and can look for this, sounds to me like a loose/disconnected neutral (white) on that branch circuit. Make sure there are no double-ups in the neutral bus bar.

Answer (score 8):

When multiple things go out, find out what they have in common.

I'm making a couple of assumptions here, since you changed out one of the sockets, you understand that the breaker must be turned off in order to work on the circuit and that you are actually using a voltmeter to make sure the circuit is dead when the breaker is off before opening up any outlet box. That this is American wiring per NEC. Also that you are **not dealing with aluminum wiring**.

1. First step is the breaker, turn it off and push it fully to the off position to reset the internal mechanism. **All** items (lights & sockets) on that circuit should die. Note what is unpowered on that circuit so you can verify later whether this is a full circuit or partial circuit power loss.
2. Turn the breaker back on and check the voltage on the breaker output in the breaker panel. If it's 92VAC there, the circuit breaker could have bad internal contacts (breaker needs to be replaced, don't mess with it if you aren't sure how to do it) or on some evilly constructed panels, the contacts to the bus bars may be bad (get an electrician IF THIS IS THE CASE, Buss bar erosion is a dangerous situation). Make sure the output lug on the circuit breaker has a tight connection.
3. If with the circuit breaker on, the same amount of items are are lacking power as were unpowered when the circuit breaker was off, you have an open connection in the wiring leading to the first socket in the daisy chain, or the incoming connection to the first socket is bad.
4. If only part of the items on the circuit come on when the breaker on, then you have a bad connection in a circuit daisy chain. When you look at intermediate sockets in the circuit, commonly a pair of wires carries power to the socket and another pair carries the power to the next socket in the chain. Find the first socket in the circuit, check voltage down the chain till you find the drop. The bad connection will be either the last socket with full power or the first one that shows the voltage drop.

Depending on the era and the electrician, the daisy chain may be continued by:

1. Wire-nutting the two cables (black to black, white to white) and running a pigtail from each to the appropriate socket connection.
2. By connecting one cable to a pair of hot and neutral screws (black/hot to brass, white/neutral to silver) and continuing the power to the next item in the chain from the second set of screws (newer sockets also allow for straight stripped wire going under a plate that's tightened by the screws)
3. By using the push-in connections on the socket in a similar configuration

My experience with a broken chain causing partial circuit power loss is with an electrician using the push-in connectors.

The failure was due to poor contact and heating that melted the first or second socket because these two sockets have to carry **all or almost all** the current in the circuit and if the wires don't enter the push-in straight or have burrs that don't allow them to seat properly you get a loose contact that gets worse over time. Heating anneals the brass and the spring contact goes away.

I haven't seen a screw tightened copper wire connection do that yet, they seem to have a larger surface area and are mechanically tightened instead of depending on spring contact.

I have seen burned aluminum screw contacts where there was a mismatch (non-CO/ALR) and bad assembly, that's another scary situation that opens up a whole 'nother can of worms.

**NOTE:** Grounding was ignored in the above discussion, bare wire goes to green screw ground lug, wire nut with pigtail is handy for this.

Comment: +1 vote for the fault being a push-in connection. It is #1 on my list of bad but allowed wiring practices. They should be banned IMO.

Comment: I replaced all the sockets in a house because they'd used cheap sockets and daisy chained them through the pushin connections. The wall mounted airconditioning was on the living room circuit, problems became apparent similar to the OPs question. The first hot connection into the first socket amazingly did not cause a fire, had melted the body while maintaining contact for quite some time if the soot in the box meant anything. Half the sockets in the house were also wired backwards, indicating the electrician's helper probably had no experience doing the job either. Makes for good feelings, eh?

Comment: I suspect the 92V is from connected hot and disconnected neutral coupling with ground. I've seen double-ups in neutral bus bars come loose.

Comment: Which is why double-ups on circuit breakers is prohibited under NEC among other things.

Comment: Excellent explanation @fiasco labs.  To the OP, one other point: Don't just look at the receptacles that are faulty.  The problem might be at the first receptacle that is faulty, it might also be at the last one that works.  That is to say that the problem can be with the wires exiting a working receptacle on it's way to the place that doesn't work.

Comment: Some breakers are listed for doubles not prohibited if listed.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, 98volts on (1) circuit w/(5) outlets. Replaced circuit breaker no change, moved circuit breaker to a new location on the bus, no change. Pulled (1) outlet and got lucky as this one had a loose neutral wire that showed signs of overheating. Replaced the entire receptacle and problem solved.

Comment: While not wrong, this doesn't add anything that wasn't already stated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a cheap, non-RMS meter? Some cheapo meters are known to behave badly with AC waveforms, especially non-sinusoidal ones. For example: if you have a dimmer elsewhere on your circuit, it could be confusing the heck out of your meter

Answer (score 0):

In the process of attempting to resolve a similar problem this evening, my son and I discovered a similar problem and our solution was not related to any of these suggestions so I though I would share the resolution we found.

This is an older home which was upgraded with a significant expansion and electrical circuits that were joined together in a manner driven by the convenience of a circuit being nearby as opposed to other factors that might appear more logical, such as putting all kitchen outlets together.

Bottom line is that the problem we encountered on two different occasions was low voltage on circuits that were downstream of a GFI. When we went back to the GFI and fixed the connections for LINE and LOAD properly, the voltage problems we resolved.

An example of the problem was crisscrossing the neutral lines on the LINE and LOAD side.

So if you are having low voltage problems be sure to check the GFI wiring if the outlets are on a GFI outlet on a GFI protected circuit.

Answer (score 0):

I have 8 indoor receptacles and one switch controlling a porch light outside. After changing out all the receptacles with tamper resistant ones I was getting 120v from line to ground, 20v neutral to ground and 95v neutral to hot.

Upon probing I found that I had one receptacle with 120v and everything else down the line only 95v. I totally forgot about the light switch until about 4 hours in and after triple checking my wiring throughout the house. I looked up at the light switch and gave her a flip and nothing. Keep in mind that i did not even work on this switch.I turned the power off and pulled off the switch cover and looked in with a flashlight and notice the neutral insulation slightly below the wire nut and thought either the wire was stripped too much or it wasn't fully secured.

Sure enough once I pulled the switch out and the neutral bundle a wire came out of the wire nut. Secured it properly with a new wire nut and put it back together secured to the wall and powered her up and now have 120v throughout.

Answer (score 0):

I changed out 5 sockets that were connected together on the same circuit protected by a single breaker. When I got done, all except this first socket in the chain showed 92V. Discovered the second socket's neutral wire had become disconnected during installation of the plug. Attached it; problem solved.

MK